# How to install M.2 SSD in GigaByte B360M Gaming HD motherboard (strange looking clip)?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, m.2

I bought a GigaByte B360M Gaming HD motherboard. ([link](https://www.gigabyte.com/in/Motherboard/B360M-GAMING-HD-rev-10#kf))

It has a weird looking M.2 connector instead of the usual screw type.

I need help in figuring out how to install the drive; Hopefully, a link to a video showing the process.

See attached images.

See the corresponding section from the manual (link here)

[YouTube video showing the image (7:22 mark)](https://youtu.be/O5IhlpKr3_s?t=442)

A few pictures of the connector is shown below:

[image: Screenshot (from the video)]

[image: Close up]

[image: Another angle]

This is all the manual says:

- Step 1: Locate the proper mounting hole for the M.2 SSD to be installed and then install the mounting clip first.
- Step 2: Slide the M.2 SSD into the connector at an angle.
- Step 3: Press the M.2 SSD down and then secure it by pressing the clip pin into the mounting hole.

[Screenshot of manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngZ2p.png)

Manual was downloaded from the official GigaByte site ([link](http://download.gigabyte.asia/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_b360m-gaming-hd_1001_e.pdf)). 
The box came with just one page booklet without any info about M.2.

Comment: Why aren't the instructions in the manual enough for you? What step exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: You can easily install the drive and here you can follow the steps https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/install-M-2-ssd.html

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a tool-less way to install the drive -

[image]

The numbers next to the holes refer to common M.2 sizes, just fit the clip to the appropriate hole, insert the M.2 cart to the socket at an angle, and lower it till it clips into place.

[image: Paint drawn picture of the installation process]

Its unclear if the clip screws or latches on - but the idea is you fit that in, then just pop in your drive... its a curious design

Answer (score 0):

Although i’m not familiar with this method of mounting M.2 cards, it looks like you (1) remove the clip from the motherboard, (2) slide the M.2 card into its socket, (4) secure the clip around the other (non-connector) side of the M.2 card and (5) press the clip (and the card) into the appropriate hole in your motherboard.

It looks like there’s not much more to it than that.